# Rails devise redirect after confirming email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to redirect to the rooth path after a users confirms his email by clicking on the activation link. The devise wiki says to implement the following method in the registrations controller:

```
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    session["user_return_to"] || root_path
  end
```

But it doesnt get picked up and keeps directing my to the following url:

http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in

How can i override this behaviour of devise?

Comment: Have you checked if the method is called? Put inside a breakpoint or a `puts` to ensure that is executed. Do you have set up the route for the registration controller?

Comment: have you tried this method [after_confirmation_path_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L40) ?

Comment: Thanks you anonymousxxx that was the method i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   root_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymousxxx posted the answer in a comment. The method is supposed to be in the confirmationscontroller.

```
module Users
  class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
    protected

    def after_confirmation_path_for(_, _)
      root_path
    end
  end
end
```